# NullReferenceException when using Portable.Ninject in Xamarin.Mac project

Tags: xamarin, ninject, inversion-of-control, xamarin.mac

I am unable to use Portable.Ninject in Xamarin.Mac project.

I am creating a container like this:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static StandardKernel Container { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new CoreModule());           

        Container = kernel;

        NSApplication.Init();
        NSApplication.Main(args);
    }
}
```

CoreModule is this:

```
public class CoreModule: NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ISettings>().To<EyeLeoSettings>().InSingletonScope ();
    }
}
```

And when I am trying to use it in AppController constructor as a service-locator:

```
private ISettings _settings;

public AppController()
{
    _settings = MainClass.Container.Get<ISettings> ();
}
```

I get NullReferenceException. Here are a few lines from a stack trace:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object   at at
>   Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.get_ParentDefinitionMethodInfo
>   ()    at at
>   Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.GetParentDefinition
>   (System.Reflection.MethodInfo,System.Reflection.BindingFlags)  ...

Please let me if using Portable.Ninject is possible in Xamarin.Mac applications. Thank you.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the same stack trace under Mono 3.2.8 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 (Mono JIT Compiler 3.2.8), any ideas?

Comment: It didn't work. I used TinyIOC and am using it happily ever after. Ninject has nothing to offer for my Xamarin project that ti can't.